# Cannot format my USB which is write protected in Windows 7

Tags: windows-explorer

I am trying to remove the write protect on my USB via regedit but cannot navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies
```

Storage appears but not `StorageDevicePolicies`. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-687538-how-to-format-a-write-protected-usb-flash-disk):

step 1:
go to this directory HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Currentcontrolset\control\
again and right click control folder

step 2:
select new, then click key and rename the new key #1 folder into
StorageDevicePolicies

step 3:
right click StorageDevicePolicies folder and select new DWORD(32-bit) Value
for 32-bit Operating System and select new DWORD(64-bit) Value
for 64-bit Operating System

step 4:
rename dword newer folder into WriteProtect, then double click WriteProtect
and change the value data into 0 with hexadecimal base, Then close regedit

step 5:
open my computer and refresh it 5 times without do anything to your usb, and
properly eject your flash drive

step 6:
plug in your usb again into your computer and format it using exfat instead of fat32

Comment: Why do you have to refresh five times? That sounds almost like Voodoo. Then again this _is_ Windows...